# Как проверить подключение к интернету?

Tags: android

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выводилось сообщение о том, что нет подключения к инету. Написал вот такой вот метод:

```
protected boolean isOnline() {
    String cs = Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(cs);
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Далее в акивити написал следующее:

```
if ( !isOnline ){
     Toast.makeText(this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
     MyActivity.this.finish();
}
```

И почему-то все-равно при дебаге этот кусок проходит насквозь. В чем проблема?
Все нужные permissions в манифесте прописал.

Comment: Думаю, просто достаточно в try{///}catch заключить тестовое соединение, и по результатам этой проверки и делать вывод о соединенности.

Мне кажется, что CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE недостаточно точно определяет состояние соединения...

Comment: Проверить невозможно.просто включить сайт и если он отказывается работать,значит интернет отсутствует

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Работает как часы:

```
public static boolean hasConnection(final Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Вызываю эту функцию внутри OnCreate, а толку все-равно 0...

Comment: обычно я считаю эту проверку лишней, потому что если нету интернета - запрос вернет ошибку и тогда можно будет ее обработать и вывести сообщение, что нету интернета, а так лишняя проверка

Comment: @Gorets, да я сам отказался сейчас от использования, но раз уж человек спросил чтоб не ответить

Answer (score 13):

Я пользуюсь вот таким методом, еще ни разу не подвел

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает как часы :)

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо автору, все работает довольно хорошо, но есть нюанс

```
protected boolean isOnline() {
    String cs = Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
    getSystemService(cs);
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {
    return false;
    } else { retrun true; }
```

Только тут я немного подкорректировал:

```
if ( !isOnline ){ 
    Toast.makeText(this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    MyActivity.this.finish();
}
```

И получилось:

```
if ( !isOnline() ){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 "Нет соединения с интернетом!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   return;
                }
```

Если вставить в обработчик `onClick` то проверка работает хорошо.

Comment: А как в случае если устройство соединилось с Wi-Fi, но интернет не проплачен или выдернут кабель?

Comment: Можно сделать так, пинговать к примеру google.com

Answer (score 1):

Чет, типа того:

```
public boolean hasConnection(final Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNW = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNW != null && activeNW.isConnected())
    {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
```

}

В основном теле:

```
if(hasConnection(this)) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Active networks OK ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   getAccountData(TOKEN, token_data_est);
}
else  Toast.makeText(this, "No active networks... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```