# Скачивание файла нажатием на кнопку, как сделать?

Tags: java, android

Нужно, сделать:
Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку скачать, начинается загрузка файла. Если интернета нет: об этот выводится сообщение. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

создайте файл AppController

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

Добавляете в manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    ...
/>
```

В build.gradle добавляете

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
}
```

И наконец сам вызов метода, он работает асинхронно, поэтому не нужно давать ему AsyncTask или еще что-то, ниже пример для строки, можно точно так же создать метод для другого файла по [ссылке](http://www.techstricks.com/download-file-using-android-volley).

```
String tag_string_req = "request";
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Подключение к серверу. Подождите...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("response",response);
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            alert.setTitle("Ошибка авторизации");
            final TextView input = new TextView(getContext());
            alert.setView(input);
            input.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);
            input.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);
            input.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.black));
            input.setText("Ошибка");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            });

            alert.show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            //Записываем параметры в запрос который передаем на сервер
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("param", param);
            return params;
        }

    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
```

Answer (score 2):

На кнопке делаете проверку:

```
public static boolean hasConnection(final Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Источник примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196349/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83)

Затем, если вернулся `true` - скачиваете.