# Фоновое выполнение задач при подключении к интернету

Tags: android

В чём суть: пользователь выполняет какое-нибудь действие, которое должно что-нибудь отправить на сервер. Если доступ к интернету есть, то оно выполняется сразу, если нет, то откладывается в ящик, однако как только доступ к интернету появился, то в фоновом режиме всё должно попасть на сервер. Получается здесь нужно использовать broadcastreceiver?

Comment: а для чего вы хотите использовать broadcastreceiver? Отслеживать состояние интернета?

Comment: лично я не вижу смысла для использования широковещательных сообщений(возможно конечно я не прав). Для проверки соединения есть системный сервис ConnectivityManager. Как его получить можете посмотреть на примере этого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196349/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83

Comment: Меня интересует не проверка интернета перед попыткой отправить на сервер запрос, а сделать так чтобы как только у телефона появится соединение с сетью, то запрос отправлялся бы на сервер. А сервис ConnectivityManager вроде как надо самому постоянно вызывать для проверки соединения. Мне нужно чтобы даже после перезагрузки устройства приложение ожидало соединения и без любых действий со стороны пользователя само делало запросы.

Comment: по-моему использование сервиса с обработкой очереди и проверкой соединения было бы надёжней. ИМХО. если возникла ошибка при запросе, который был поднят по сообщению...следующего раза ждать пока сеть пропадёт и появится снова?.. Если изначально запрос попал в очередь не из-за сети?...у меня сеть без сбоев может очень долго работать.

Comment: поднять приложение с помощью broadcastreceiver, при появлении сети можно, но лично я бы так не делал...

Comment: Правильное направление. Ресивер запускает сервис очевидно, остальное зависит от реализации.

Comment: Сервис в отдельным потоке, в котором крутится цикл на проверку сети. Если есть сеть, то отправляем Ваш запрос